# How to render view template via controller

Tags: php, laravel

I want to reuse the same `return View::make('pages.home');` template view for my `UserController` but I am not sure how to connect the view to that controller.

I am assuming I need to put something in my `index` of my controller but I am not exactly sure what as this is my first time with Laravel.

Here is my current code:

`Routes.php`

```
<?php

Route::get('/home', function () {
  return View::make('pages.home');
});

Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');

Route::get('/foo', function () {
    return 'taobao';
});
```

`UserController.php //simplified`

```
public function index()
{
  $this->oauth();
  return view('user', ['name' => 'James']);
}
```

Comment: dont find any mistake here, what are you facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to reuse the same `return View::make('pages.home');` or home view in your UserController you can call it as

```
return view('home', ['name' => 'James']);
```

or you need to include home view in users view then you can do

```
@extends('home') or @include('home')
```

Comment: I was totally overthinking this really just had to change it to home

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
public function index()
{
  $this->oauth();
  $user = ['name' => 'James'];
  return view('user', compact('user'));
}
```

Now you can call `$user` in user view. 
Example (using blade): `{{ $user['name'] }}`, the output would be `James`

Answer (score 1):

You don't exactly need to connect your view to the controller in Laravel. You just need to put your view to the specific location (Either default or intended).

After you have made your view and stored in the view directory, You can call it inside any controller. There is no strict connection between views and controller in MVC.

You just need to return `return View::make('pages.home');` from any controller action you want and reuse it as many times. Or, you can use the helper instead `return view('pages.home');`

Hope that is what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put anything specific to the `index()` method of your Controller. Think of a Controller as the Brains that ehemmm.. "control" what's going to happen, either a long query to the database, calculating some operations, returning a view, or a combination of all.

In your code above `Route::get('/', 'UserController@index');` is actually binding the `/` "address" or route to the method `index()` of your `UserController`.

In regards to what you asked, you need to split up your `pages.home` view so it can be reusable. I recommend you reading the [templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) documentation.

In short, you could have the following page, called `base.blade.php`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap includes -->
    <!-- JS Includes -->
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div class="content">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, we can create 2 more pages.

`users.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('content')

    <div> Hello Users!</div>    

@endsection
```

`admins.blade.php`:

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('content')

    <div> Hello Admins!</div>    

@endsection
```

Those two blade templates will inject the HTML inside their correspondent sections, in this case content, into the template `base.blade.php` whenever they are called. That way, you can "reuse" a view, which is very efficient since changing `base.blade.php` will change all the views that "inject" or inherit from it.

Now, like you said, in order to "connect" the view to a controller, you simply need to return a view from within a method in that controller. For example:

`MyController.php`:

```
MyController extends Controller{

    ...

    public function index()
    {
        // Fancy stuff you might wanna do...

        // Note this will pull the view from within the layout folder
        return view('users');
    }

}
```

Of course, you need to have a route that is paired with that Controller and that method, which in this case you do.

I hope this helps!

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try this:

Added below line in your `user.blade.php`

```
@include('pages.home')
```